# Flash videos in WebView not working in sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2, sandbox

I'm having a problem with playing flash videos in my application.  It's been working before, but ever since Apple has required every developer to enable entitlements and sandboxing, flash videos in the webview do not play.  Everytime I disable sandboxing, it works, but if sandboxing is enabled, it doesn't.  Below I've posted links images of the Sandboxing and Entitlements settings. Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpvJ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6OVy.png

Comment: According to an Apple employee on the Apple Developer Forums this is a bug. You should [file a bug report](http://filearadar.com/).

Comment: I just filed a bug report now. At least I know I'm not going crazy... I hope it's resolved quickly. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

figured out how to fix it...

go to your entitlements and add:

```
KEY:  com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name    TYPE:Array
```

then add a string to the array with the value:

```
com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent
```

This sets a temporary exception each time the application is run, giving the app permission to run the PluginAgent.