# Flash player doesn't work in Webview when App Sandboxing is enabled

Tags: objective-c, webview, flash, entitlements, appstore-sandbox

I'm developing a Mac app for desktop, the app uses a **Webview** to load certain urls. Every things works fine, but when I enabled the **"Enable App Sandboxing"** option and the correct entitlements for the app, the Flash Player Pluging doesn't load in the Webview.

I tried the answer for this question: [Flash videos in WebView not working in sandboxed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281666/flash-videos-in-webview-not-working-in-sandboxed-app). but the flash plugin still not working. Also I tried with **Clean** product option (cmd + shift + alt + k), but still not working.

What need to do to achieve it?, I need to show the Flash Player plugin in the Webview when the  App Sandboxing is enabled.

Comment: I found this link where is talking about the issue but I don't understand nothing, who can guide me to resolve this issue?. http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2395401

Comment: Sorty, can't help you with that question but I was still wondering. What are you planning to do for users who don't have flash installed? If I remember correctly it doesn't come preinstalled anymore. Some people (like me) even uninstall it.

Comment: I know it, I'm developing a secure web browser for kids and its contens is 90% flash based, this software is not for me, is for a customer. If the mac has not installed the flash player and the user want to use the app, he needs install flash. My work is guarantee that the app run flash movies.

Comment: Do you see any sandbox violations reported for your application in Console at the time it tries to load the Flash plug-in? Are there any other messages printed in Console at the time your application is launched?

Comment: When I open the app, the Console prints:
24/01/13 12:41:53,140 appleeventsd[51]: <rdar://problem/11489077> A sandboxed application with pid 838, "AppName" checked in with appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be validated ( either because it was corrupt, or could not be read by appleeventsd ) and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by name, bundle id, or signature. Error=ERROR: #100013  { "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopyGuestWithAttributes() returned 100013, -." }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #1725) com.apple.coreservices.appleevents.peer.0x7ff8386224a0.xpcq

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, try adding an exception for Apple Events. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW1

I don't know if you tried that, but the StackOverflow answer you referenced doesn't seem related to the problem you have.

Comment: Hi!, I was trying of fix my issue with the "Apple Event Temporary Exception" without success, seems to the console error doesn't has relate with my current problem.