# Playing Vimeo Video in Sandboxed Mac OS x App?

Tags: macos, vimeo

As for now i have created a mac OS X app for some video tutorials stuff.The files are hoasted up in vimeo and i designed to show up in webview .Everything works fine but due to  Apple's SandBoxing  i found the videos are not playing just getting blank screen.Is there any way to play the vimeo videos in Sandboxed mac OS x application..?

[image: Sandboxing Option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i figured it out..Actually connections are established but the video stuffs are not playing due to the flash plugin that was disabled due to sand-boxing.Thanks to [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281666/flash-videos-in-webview-not-working-in-sandboxed-app).This really helped me and finally my app was in app store.!!!!