# Embedding youtube video doesn't work anymore in Mavericks

Tags: cocoa, video, youtube, embedding

In my cocoa apps for OSX 10.6 and newer versions I've always used this code to embed a video from youtube:

```
NSString *html = @"<center><iframe width=\"748\" height=\"461\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/SV1cVDhKZ6g?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>";

  [[videoView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

but now it is not working anymore, it just appears a black window and if I click on it I can still hear audio from video but no image anymore...
I'm using Maverick and Xcode 5...
Anyone knows what can be the problem?
Thanks for any help.
Massy

**update**: I'm also noticing that if I double click on video frame to see it fullscreen the video appears... but when I double click again to make it framed in my app the image of the video disappears again

**update 2**: As pointed by ThisDarkTao I can now say this is a problem concerning Safari's Flash sandbox.
I tryed the solution by this post:

> [Flash videos in WebView not working in sandboxed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281666/flash-videos-in-webview-not-working-in-sandboxed-app)

but it didn't work at all...

During my research I read somewhere that someone says this must be a bug... I'm not so sure about it... I think this is exactly what Apple wants... finally flash is always been a bad topic for guys at Cupertino... isn't it?

I'm sure there must be a solution to this....

If anyone knows a better solution please write it... If none will give a better solution I will accept the answer of ThisDarkTao as it seams for now is the only way to make it work.

Comment: This isn't an Xcode problem... Are you developing an app for OSX Mavericks or iOS 7, your question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: I'm developing for OSX 10.6 and newer... I also think that this is not related to an Xcode problem... but I don't know what to think... I tryed to install flash player again but with no results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a problem concerning Safari's Flash sandbox. I have the same problem on a Mavericks app I'm developing at the moment. I added `html5=1` to the video arguments list, effectively forcing HTML5 video.

Yours in that case would be:

```
NSString *html = @"<center><iframe width=\"748\" height=\"461\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/SV1cVDhKZ6g?rel=0&html5=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>";
```

If you definitely need Flash, I haven't been able to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: It works... thanks a lot... the only problem now is that video can't be opened full screen anymore... do you have a solution to that also?

Comment: You can allow fullscreen for WebKit browsers by adding `webkitallowfullscreen` to your player's iframe. Currently fullscreen and the `iv_load_policy` parameter to hide annotations do not work on Safari 7.0 (9537.71), but do work on Safari 6. I can only assume this is a bug with Googles iframe code, unless the sandboxing is disabling iframe fullscreen also. I'm filing a bug report with Apple about the fullscreen and annotation issues, so hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Comment: It doesn't work... I replaced "allowfullscreen" with "webkitallowfullscreen" but it still doesn't go in fullscreen...

Comment: If I manage to find out any more info or fix the fullscreen problem I'll revive this question.